# Page not showing database updated info but database is updated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a standard form that displays a user's current data from a MySQL database once logged in (code obtained from the internet). Users can then edit their data then submit it to page called editform.php that does the update.

Everything works well except that the page does not display the updated info. Users have to first logout and login again to see the updated info. Refreshing the page does not show the new info.

My form test.php

```
<form action="editform.php?id_user=<?= $fgmembersite->UserId() ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserId() ?>"><br>
    Name:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="name" size="40" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName() ?>"><br><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" size="40" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail() ?>  "><br><br>
    Address:<br>
    <input type="text" name="address" size="40" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserAddress() ?>  "><br><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
```

my editform.php page

```
<?php


include('db.php');

 mysql_query("UPDATE fgusers3 SET name = '".$_POST['name']."', email=                  `enter code here`'".$_POST['email']."', address= '".$_POST['address']."' WHERE       `enter code here`id_user='".$_POST['id_user']."'");

header("Location: test.php");
```

?>

my membersite_config.php

```
 <?PHP
 require_once("./include/fg_membersite.php");

 $fgmembersite = new FGMembersite();


 $fgmembersite->SetWebsiteName('user11.com');


 $fgmembersite->SetAdminEmail('user11@user11.com');


 $fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
                  /*username*/'',
                  /*password*/'',
                  /*database name*/'',
                  /*table name*/'fgusers3');


 $fgmembersite->SetRandomKey('qSRcVS6DrTzrPvr');

 ?>
```

my fg_membersite.php page

```
 <?PHP

 require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
 require_once("formvalidator.php");

class FGMembersite
{
var $admin_email;
var $from_address;

var $username;
var $pwd;
var $database;
var $tablename;
var $connection;
var $rand_key;

var $error_message;

//-----Initialization -------
function FGMembersite()
{
    $this->sitename = 'YourWebsiteName.com';
    $this->rand_key = '0iQx5oBk66oVZep';
}

function InitDB($host,$uname,$pwd,$database,$tablename)
{
    $this->db_host  = $host;
    $this->username = $uname;
    $this->pwd  = $pwd;
    $this->database  = $database;
    $this->tablename = $tablename;

}
function SetAdminEmail($email)
{
    $this->admin_email = $email;
}

function SetWebsiteName($sitename)
{
    $this->sitename = $sitename;
}

function SetRandomKey($key)
{
    $this->rand_key = $key;
}

//-------Main Operations ----------------------
function RegisterUser()
{
    if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
       return false;
    }

    $formvars = array();

    if(!$this->ValidateRegistrationSubmission())
    {
        return false;
    }

    $this->CollectRegistrationSubmission($formvars);

    if(!$this->SaveToDatabase($formvars))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!$this->SendUserConfirmationEmail($formvars))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $this->SendAdminIntimationEmail($formvars);

    return true;
  }

 function ConfirmUser()
  {
    if(empty($_GET['code'])||strlen($_GET['code'])<=10)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Please provide the confirm code");
        return false;
    }
    $user_rec = array();
    if(!$this->UpdateDBRecForConfirmation($user_rec))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $this->SendUserWelcomeEmail($user_rec);

    $this->SendAdminIntimationOnRegComplete($user_rec);

    return true;
 }    

 function Login()
 {
     if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;

    return true;
   }

   function CheckLogin()
   {
     if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

     $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

     if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
     {
        return false;
     }
     return true;
    }

    function UserId()
    {
    return isset($_SESSION['id_of_user'])?$_SESSION['id_of_user']:'';
    }


    function UserFullName()
    {
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
    }

    function UserEmail()
    {
    return isset($_SESSION['email_of_user'])?$_SESSION['email_of_user']:'';
    }

    function UserAddress()
    {
    return isset($_SESSION['address_of_user'])?$_SESSION['address_of_user']:'';
    }


    function LogOut()
   {
    session_start();

    $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

    $_SESSION[$sessionvar]=NULL;

    unset($_SESSION[$sessionvar]);
}

function EmailResetPasswordLink()
{
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Email is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    $user_rec = array();
    if(false === $this->GetUserFromEmail($_POST['email'], $user_rec))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(false === $this->SendResetPasswordLink($user_rec))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function ResetPassword()
{
    if(empty($_GET['email']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Email is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    if(empty($_GET['code']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("reset code is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    $email = trim($_GET['email']);
    $code = trim($_GET['code']);

    if($this->GetResetPasswordCode($email) != $code)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Bad reset code!");
        return false;
    }

    $user_rec = array();
    if(!$this->GetUserFromEmail($email,$user_rec))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $new_password = $this->ResetUserPasswordInDB($user_rec);
    if(false === $new_password || empty($new_password))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error updating new password");
        return false;
    }

    if(false == $this->SendNewPassword($user_rec,$new_password))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error sending new password");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function ChangePassword()
{
    if(!$this->CheckLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Not logged in!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['oldpwd']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Old password is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    if(empty($_POST['newpwd']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("New password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $user_rec = array();
    if(!$this->GetUserFromEmail($this->UserEmail(),$user_rec))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $pwd = trim($_POST['oldpwd']);

    if($user_rec['password'] != md5($pwd))
    {
        $this->HandleError("The old password does not match!");
        return false;
    }
    $newpwd = trim($_POST['newpwd']);

    if(!$this->ChangePasswordInDB($user_rec, $newpwd))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//-------Public Helper functions -------------
function GetSelfScript()
{
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}    

function SafeDisplay($value_name)
{
    if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
    {
        return'';
    }
    return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
}

function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function GetSpamTrapInputName()
{
    return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->rand_key);
}

function GetErrorMessage()
{
    if(empty($this->error_message))
    {
        return '';
    }
    $errormsg = nl2br(htmlentities($this->error_message));
    return $errormsg;
}    
//-------Private Helper functions-----------

function HandleError($err)
{
    $this->error_message .= $err."\r\n";
}

function HandleDBError($err)
{
    $this->HandleError($err."\r\n mysqlerror:".mysql_error());
}

function GetFromAddress()
{
    if(!empty($this->from_address))
    {
        return $this->from_address;
    }

    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    $from ="nobody@$host";
    return $from;
} 

function GetLoginSessionVar()
{
    $retvar = md5($this->rand_key);
    $retvar = 'usr_'.substr($retvar,0,10);
    return $retvar;
}

function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }          
    $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);
    $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
    $qry = "Select id_user, name, email, address from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
        return false;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    $_SESSION['id_of_user'] = $row['id_user'];
    $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['address_of_user'] = $row['address'];


    return true;
}

function UpdateDBRecForConfirmation(&$user_rec)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }   
    $confirmcode = $this->SanitizeForSQL($_GET['code']);

    $result = mysql_query("Select name, email from $this->tablename where confirmcode='$confirmcode'",$this->connection);   
    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Wrong confirm code.");
        return false;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $user_rec['name'] = $row['name'];
    $user_rec['email']= $row['email'];

    $qry = "Update $this->tablename Set confirmcode='y' Where  confirmcode='$confirmcode'";

    if(!mysql_query( $qry ,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$qry");
        return false;
    }      
    return true;
}

function ResetUserPasswordInDB($user_rec)
{
    $new_password = substr(md5(uniqid()),0,10);

    if(false == $this->ChangePasswordInDB($user_rec,$new_password))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $new_password;
}

function ChangePasswordInDB($user_rec, $newpwd)
{
    $newpwd = $this->SanitizeForSQL($newpwd);

    $qry = "Update $this->tablename Set password='".md5($newpwd)."' Where  id_user=".$user_rec['id_user']."";

    if(!mysql_query( $qry ,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error updating the password \nquery:$qry");
        return false;
    }     
    return true;
}

function GetUserFromEmail($email,&$user_rec)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }   
    $email = $this->SanitizeForSQL($email);

    $result = mysql_query("Select * from $this->tablename where email='$email'",$this->connection);  

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("There is no user with email: $email");
        return false;
    }
    $user_rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    return true;
}

function SendUserWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'],$user_rec['name']);

    $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

    $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
    "Welcome! Your registration  with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    "Regards,\r\n".
    "Webmaster\r\n".
    $this->sitename;

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function SendAdminIntimationOnRegComplete(&$user_rec)
{
    if(empty($this->admin_email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

    $mailer->Subject = "Registration Completed: ".$user_rec['name'];

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

    $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Name: ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n".
    "Email address: ".$user_rec['email']."\r\n";

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function GetResetPasswordCode($email)
{
   return substr(md5($email.$this->sitename.$this->rand_key),0,10);
}

function SendResetPasswordLink($user_rec)
{
    $email = $user_rec['email'];

    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mailer->AddAddress($email,$user_rec['name']);

    $mailer->Subject = "Your reset password request at ".$this->sitename;

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

    $link = $this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder().
            '/resetpwd.php?email='.
            urlencode($email).'&code='.
            urlencode($this->GetResetPasswordCode($email));

    $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
    "There was a request to reset your password at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Please click the link below to complete the request: \r\n".$link."\r\n".
    "Regards,\r\n".
    "Webmaster\r\n".
    $this->sitename;

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function SendNewPassword($user_rec, $new_password)
{
    $email = $user_rec['email'];

    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mailer->AddAddress($email,$user_rec['name']);

    $mailer->Subject = "Your new password for ".$this->sitename;

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

    $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
    "Your password is reset successfully. ".
    "Here is your updated login:\r\n".
    "username:".$user_rec['username']."\r\n".
    "password:$new_password\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    "Login here: ".$this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder()."/login.php\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    "Regards,\r\n".
    "Webmaster\r\n".
    $this->sitename;

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}    

function ValidateRegistrationSubmission()
{
    //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
    if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
    {
        //The proper error is not given intentionally
        $this->HandleError("Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed");
        return false;
    }

    $validator = new FormValidator();
    $validator->addValidation("name","req","Please fill in Name");
    $validator->addValidation("email","email","The input for Email should be a valid email value");
    $validator->addValidation("email","req","Please fill in Email");
    $validator->addValidation("username","req","Please fill in UserName");
    $validator->addValidation("password","req","Please fill in Password");


    if(!$validator->ValidateForm())
    {
        $error='';
        $error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
        foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
        {
            $error .= $inpname.':'.$inp_err."\n";
        }
        $this->HandleError($error);
        return false;
    }        
    return true;
}

function CollectRegistrationSubmission(&$formvars)
{
    $formvars['name'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
    $formvars['email'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);
    $formvars['username'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['username']);
    $formvars['password'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['password']);
}

function SendUserConfirmationEmail(&$formvars)
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mailer->AddAddress($formvars['email'],$formvars['name']);

    $mailer->Subject = "Your registration with ".$this->sitename;

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

    $confirmcode = $formvars['confirmcode'];

    $confirm_url = $this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder().'/confirmreg.php?code='.$confirmcode;

    $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$formvars['name']."\r\n\r\n".
    "Thanks for your registration with ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Please click the link below to confirm your registration.\r\n".
    "$confirm_url\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    "Regards,\r\n".
    "Webmaster\r\n".
    $this->sitename;

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Failed sending registration confirmation email.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function GetAbsoluteURLFolder()
{
    $scriptFolder = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    $urldir ='';
    $pos = strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
    if(false !==$pos)
    {
        $urldir = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,$pos);
    }

    $scriptFolder .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$urldir;

    return $scriptFolder;
}

function SendAdminIntimationEmail(&$formvars)
{
    if(empty($this->admin_email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

    $mailer->Subject = "New registration: ".$formvars['name'];

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

    $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Name: ".$formvars['name']."\r\n".
    "Email address: ".$formvars['email']."\r\n".
    "UserName: ".$formvars['username'];

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function SaveToDatabase(&$formvars)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }
    if(!$this->Ensuretable())
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!$this->IsFieldUnique($formvars,'email'))
    {
        $this->HandleError("This email is already registered");
        return false;
    }

    if(!$this->IsFieldUnique($formvars,'username'))
    {
        $this->HandleError("This UserName is already used. Please try another username");
        return false;
    }        
    if(!$this->InsertIntoDB($formvars))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Inserting to Database failed!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function IsFieldUnique($formvars,$fieldname)
{
    $field_val = $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars[$fieldname]);
    $qry = "select username from $this->tablename where $fieldname='".$field_val."'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);   
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function DBLogin()
{

    $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host,$this->username,$this->pwd);

    if(!$this->connection)
    {   
        $this->HandleDBError("Database Login failed! Please make sure that the DB login credentials provided are correct");
        return false;
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError('Failed to select database: '.$this->database.' Please make sure that the database name provided is correct');
        return false;
    }
    if(!mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'",$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError('Error setting utf8 encoding');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}    

function Ensuretable()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $this->tablename");   
    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        return $this->CreateTable();
    }
    return true;
}

function CreateTable()
{
    $qry = "Create Table $this->tablename (".
            "id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,".
            "name VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "phone_number VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,".
            "confirmcode VARCHAR(32) ,".
            "PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )".
            ")";

    if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
{

    $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

    $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

    $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
            name,
            email,
            username,
            password,
            confirmcode
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
            "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
            "' . $confirmcode . '"
            )';      
    if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
        return false;
    }        
    return true;
}
function MakeConfirmationMd5($email)
{
    $randno1 = rand();
    $randno2 = rand();
    return md5($email.$this->rand_key.$randno1.''.$randno2);
}
function SanitizeForSQL($str)
{
    if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
    {
          $ret_str = mysql_real_escape_string( $str );
    }
    else
    {
          $ret_str = addslashes( $str );
    }
    return $ret_str;
}


function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
{
    $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

    if($remove_nl)
    {
        $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
            '/(\r+)/i',
            '/(\t+)/i',
            '/(%0A+)/i',
            '/(%0D+)/i',
            '/(%08+)/i',
            '/(%09+)/i'
            );
        $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
    }

    return $str;
}    
function StripSlashes($str)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

}
?>

Comment: you have to call the database again. Because by the time you post the values you still have the older values in the php mysql_query() memory.

Comment: You posted WAY WAY too much code. No one is going to read that much code.

Comment: Would that be on the test.php page and how do i call the database again...bare in mind i am still a newbie...

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query` it's [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: If you want to find the problem, remove things of your code bit by bit until the problem disapears, then you'll know. At least, please remove everything unecessary to expose the issue, so that it becomes manageable for us.

Comment: everything works well except that the ammended data does not display after header("location:test.php") the old data still shows. Once the user logs out and back in again the ammended data now shows. Maybe got to do with the sessions.

Comment: I think @eddwinpaz gave you the right answer.

Comment: so how do i call the database again. sorry for the silly question

Comment: Make a select using the same value to fill the fields again

Comment: But only make this if a user post the update

Comment: @eddwinpaz if you can give me a sample code it will be great.thanks in advance

Comment: You do an update right? so after the update call, make another query calling the same data again with the ID of the row you just updated and then pass it to the $fgmembersit so you can show the updated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. For those of you who would have a similar problem i thought i would share with you. In my editform.php i was succesfully updating the database but i was not updating the session.Since i was retrieving the values from the session and not the database, the updated info was not showing hence i needed to update the session with $_SESSION['name_of_user'] = $_POST['name']; for name as well as all the other values i was retrieving. –

Answer (score 0):

editform.php shows info that are stored to session during login, so even after the update to the table the  session will have the old value

change your code in function UserAddress() to fetch address from the database not from session.
And update the address value in session address after the update query to table(fgusers3)